# How to write `this.props` when rewriting class components to functional components with state hooks?

Tags: reactjs

How to write `this.props` when rewriting class components to  functional components with state hooks?
for example:

```
class BasicLayout extends PureComponent { 
  render() { 
    //...
    const { children, location, loading } = this.props;  
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?

Answer (score 2):

When using a functional Component the props are available as a function argument with or without hooks. The above class component can simply be written as

```
const BasicLayout = (props) => { 
    //...
    const { children, location, loading } = props;  
    // ...
}
```

Hooks do not affect the manner in which you use props but provide APIs to use `state, context, lifecycle implementation` in functional components using `useState, useContext, useEffect` hooks